# Adjust CurrentDate for another timezone in SharePoint 2010 / XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a legacy SharePoint 2010 application I am supporting and I need to adjust an xsl parameter for another time zone, right now it's Eastern time and I need it to be Pacific.

The app uses `<xsl:param name="today">CurrentDate</xsl:param>` which spits out the current date and time (server time) I then log the time to a list and go on about my business.

The problem is that I don't have access to C# and I need to subtract four hours of the $today parameter I set. Any ideas???

Note the $today param shows the date like this: 2016-08-19T01:16:16Z

EDIT:

How about any date/time calculation on CurrentDate or  in SharePoint

Comment: This is confusing: I thought you wanted to convert from Eastern Time to Pacific Time. But the dateTime that you show is UTC. -- Note also that the difference between Eastern and Pacific Time is three hours, not four.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. See if you can adapt the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582985/need-help-in-xslt-for-timezone-conversion/37583483#37583483